# How do I get my PHP update function to work?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

See something wrong in my code? I can't get the update function to work.. weird thing is the rest works correctly, and the same code works 100% on another page.

```
<?php
include("config.php");

$id = $_GET['id'];

$number = $_GET['no'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE commentid = '$id'")
or die(mysql_error());  

$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

mysql_query("update `comments` set like = like +1 where commentid = '$id'"); <--- only this here doesnt work
?>
```

And there is 1 line of html after that, a span tag getting some information out of the comments table.
My 'like' column is set to int(11), so I don't see that being the problem.

Hope this isnt another innatention mistake :/

Thanks alot to anyone who can help me out!

This is the error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'like = like
>   +1 where commentid = '61'' at line 1

Comment: For one, LIKE is a reserved MySQL keyword.

Comment: so should i change my column name, or adding brackets around would work?

Answer (score 2):

As EboMike posted, LIKE is a reserved keyword in MySQL.

You can either rename your column to something else that is not a keyword (preferred), or you can put a backtick (a backwards single quote) around it to tell MySQL it's a literal name.

Comment: Not single quotes, but backticks.

Comment: I've tried both in phpMyAdmin and they both work. I'll update my answer all the same. Thanks.

Comment: Rename your column.  Quoting it will work, but it'll cause you more pain later.  Just rename it.

Comment: While you are at it, trying to make sure you sanitize your inputs before placing them into a SQL query. This is how SQL injection attacks occur.